# Cannot add content to a div after using empty() on it

Tags: jquery, dom

I'm trying to add content to a `<div>` after using `empty()` on it's parent. But somehow, it wont work. Why wont this work? If I don't use `empty()` things work. But why not after using `empty()`

What I'm trying is to empty the parent that contains the links `.acceptUser` or `.rejectUser` and add fresh links. New content needs to go inside the `parent div`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Side bar poll thingy</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/site/scripts/jQueryCore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/site/scripts/rsCore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/site/scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.acceptUser, .rejectUser').click(function() {

    var action = $(this).attr('class');
    var type = $(this).data('id');

    console.log(action+' '+type);
    console.log($(this).parent());

    $(this).parent("div").empty();
    // Wont work : $(this).parent("div").after("<div class='flag'>Success</div>");
    // Wont work : $(this).parent("div").append("<div class='flag'>Success</div>");


  });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
UserName : Norman | SignedUp: 10-09-2013 | SignedUp Location: US

<div class="adminLinks">
    <span class="acceptUser" data-id="24">Accept</span>
    <span class="rejectUser" data-id="24">Reject</span>
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *"[...] after using `empty()` on it's parent."* Because the element doesn't exist anymore. At least it's not a child of its parent anymore.

Comment: define `var $(this).parent("div");` global and then try...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.acceptUser, .rejectUser').click(function () {
        var action = $(this).attr('class');
        var type = $(this).data('id');
        console.log(action + ' ' + type);
        console.log($(this).parent());
        var parentTag = $(this).parent("div");
        parentTag.empty();
        parentTag.after("<div class='flag'>Success</div>");
        parentTag.append("<div class='flag'>Success</div>");
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/E8UVE/

Answer (score 1):

Store `$(this).parent("div").empty();` into a variable because it won't be available after `empty()`

So

```
var $parent = $(this).parent("div");    
 $parent.empty();
 $parent.after("<div class='flag'>Success</div>");
 $parent.append("<div class='flag'>Success</div>");
```

Answer (score 1):

After you called `.empty`, the parent-child relationship is lost. `.empty` removes all children of the element. The next time you call `.parent('div')`, you will get back an empty jQuery object because `this` has no parent anymore.

The easiest solution is to use method chaining:

```
$(this).parent("div")
  .empty()
  .after("<div class='flag'>Success</div>")
  .append("<div class='flag'>Success</div>");
```